# Can't get my regex to work

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract text between some tags from a html response page using C#.

```
<input type="hidden" name="79bddb76e349d12a5be85c0d183923f7" value="1" />
```

I need the value 79bddb76e349d12a5be85c0d183923f7. Only this value change, the part value=1 remains same every time. Also note that there are two other hidden fields before this one :

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="example" />

<input type="hidden" name="task" value="login" />
```

So do I need to use matchcollections? What will be the regex?

Thanks.

Comment: start with a simple regex match then try to add more and more parts. you probably won't succeed writing the whole regex in one run if you are a beginner.

Answer (score 4):

You could try parsing the document into XHTML, and then use XPath to extract the information you need:

```
//input[@value = '1']/name
```

With regex, you could use something along these lines:

```
name="([^"]+)" value="1"
```

Comment: new Regex("\"name=\"([^\"]+)\" value=\"1\"");

Answer (score 0):

Generally, parsing the document as XHTML is preferred to using regexes on the HTML directly, since parsing HTML using regular expressions can be fragile.  But if you do want to use regular expressions, something like this will probably work:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetNamesInHtml(string html)
{
    const string pattern = @"<input type=\""hidden\"" "
           + @"name=\""([0-9a-f]{32})\"" value=\""1\"" />";
    return Regex.Matches(html, pattern)
         .OfType<Match>()
         .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value); 
}
```

As a driver:

```
string input = @"<input type=""hidden"" name=""79bddb76e349d12a5be85c0d183923f7"" value=""1"" />
           other html <b>sldkjflsdkjf</b> ipsum 
           <input type=""hidden"" name=""task"" value=""login"" />
           <input type=""hidden"" name=""33947f979873987d9879283473a98738"" value=""1"" /> ";
foreach (string s in GetNamesInHtml(input))
    Console.WriteLine(s);
// prints:
// 79bddb76e349d12a5be85c0d183923f7
// 33947f979873987d9879283473a98738
```